# I am unable to configure websockify, nodejs and java implementations the server i am using is TightVNC

Tags: python, node.js, websockify

Basically I want to run websockify for proxying for websockets, the python version is a far cry for windows. I need detailed specific help, link or anything explaining how to configure/use websockify with nodejs or java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js works fine in Windows. It has a subset of the same parameters as the python version. For example, to listen on `localhost` port 6080 and connect to `vncserver` port 5901 and serve the web files from the current directory, run it like this:

```
node other/js/websockify.js --web ./ localhost:6080 vncserver:5901
```

Comment: And then what URL do I use to connect?  I assume it something like http://localhost:6080?wsirc.html?host=localhost&port=6080 but that doesn't appear to be connecting for me.  I have the python websockify working (not at the same time, that would be a conflict), so I know I can connect via noVNC, just don't know how to use the node websockify.

Comment: Are you running your browser on the same machine? Also, make sure you load the HTML via a web server and not by opening a local file directly (e.g. file://) because local file pages are not allowed to make websocket connections.

Comment: Thanks for trying kanaka, it seems that hosting the page got me a little farther, but I am still not understanding what is happening, and it isn't working.  My project has the python version of noVNC/websockify working now, so while I am curious, I won't be spending more time on this.